# Fancybox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

i has a problem. I must change Fancybox to when i click 'next' in gallery then show next img with next number in 'rel'. I know fancybox work on 'data-fancybox-group' and i have this code but i have script to sort foto. this script is isotope. Maybe anyone know how integrate isotope with fancybox? but ok, i write script to write attribute rel and work good. 
Now i needs change fancybox to download number from "rel" and show next number.

Sory my english is no good :)

Thanks :)

Comment: can you provide us some code, Lukaszu

Comment: Check this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/ncVsViD2v9o if that helps